# Dealing with Node's async nature - writeFile callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, coffeescript

I have the following function within a CoffeeScript class:

```
 use: (db, fn) ->
    fs.exists db, (exists) =>
      if exists?
        @db = db
        @_fetch()
      else
        fs.writeFile db, {}, (err) =>
          if err 
            err
          else 
            @db = db
            @_fetch()
```

What bothers me is that I had to write `@db = db` and `@_fetch()` twice. The reason I had to do this was that the `else` clause calls on `fs.writeFile` which is asynchronous. Therefore, I had to put those two lines inside `writeFile`'s callback to make sure they didn't fire too soon.

Is there a way, however, to clean this up and write those lines ones? It's *only* two lines at the moment, but what if the callback exists of 10 lines? Would get messy, no?

Any other feedback on this small piece of code is welcome too. Not that sure about the error handling (just returning `err` at the moment..).

Comment: `fn` is your callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript has functions and [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) allows you to bind a function to an instance so why not just chop your code up into bound functions?

```
use: (db, fn) ->
  fetch = =>
    @db = db
    @_fetch()
  fs.exists db, (exists) =>
    if exists?
      fetch()
    else
      fs.writeFile db, {}, (err) =>
        if err 
          err
        else 
          fetch()
```

Then add whatever else (such as calling `fn`) needs to be done to `fetch`.

Also, I don't think your:

```
if err
  err
```

error handling does anything. I'm not a node.js expert but, AFAIK, [`writeFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) doesn't care what the callback returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a helper function:

```
use: (db, fn) ->
  helper = () =>
    @db = db
    @_fetch()
    …
    fn(null, result)

  fs.exists db, (exists) =>
    if exists
      helper()
    else
      fs.writeFile db, {}, (err) ->
        if err
          fn(err)
        else
          helper()
        return
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the only time you don't want to load the DB and fetch is if the db does not exist and the subsequent loading produces an error, you could try something like this...

```
use: (db, fn) ->
    fs.exists db, (exists) =>
    if not exists?
        fs.writeFile db, {}, (err) =>
            if err 
                return err

    @db = db
    @_fetch()
```